# Bootstrap 3 template that has everything on one page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, themes

I am trying to build my own theme, but I am looking for a good markup page that has all the components and buttons, and navs, and such all on one page. I have tried to create one myself and I just don't have everything that you would see on a theme preview website. Is there a good markup available?

Comment: This one would help as well: http://bootflat.github.io/documentation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if i get you right, but normaly those both links should give you a good starting point! very well documented:

[Bootstrap getting started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

[Bootstrap Components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)

Comment: hmm.. did you scroll down a bit? its a very long page with all components, bootstrap has... the glyphicons are a bit irritating at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Talking about that you can find it in the bootstrap website.
In the components of that site.This component tab has all the components but you can also check the javascript tab

http://getbootstrap.com/components/

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/